# Javascript json object and wcf webservice bad request

Tags: c#, jquery, json, wcf, web-services

I have been successfully using wcf webservices to do some simple operations. Now I'm trying to pass a more complex object using jquery ajax post but this time I have always the same error (bad request). I have searched a lot but still could not identify the problem

Here's what I'm trying to do:

My interface

```
[OperationContract(Name = "PersonAddress")]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddPersonAddress/", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
PersonAddress AddPersonAddress(PersonAddress objPA);
```

My Javascript test code:

```
var testObj = {
      cpostal: "Postal 1",
      address: "My address",
      zone:""
}

var objectAsJson = JSON.stringify({ objPA: testObj });

$.post('../../App_Services/DataService.svc/PersonAddress/', objectAsJson, function (data) {
      alert("success");
});
```

`PersonAddress` structure

```
public class PersonAddress
{
    public string cpostal { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string zone { get; set; }
}
```

Chrome console post

```
{"objP":{"cpostal":"Postal 1","address": "My address","zone":""}}
```

according to these  articles:

[Link 1](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/passing-json-serialized-objects-wcf-service-jquery)
[Link 2](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/passing-json-serialized-objects-wcf-service-jquery)

I have to send a string that is the JSON representation of a JS object which properties matches the parameter name of the function that i'm calling.

Comment: Why do you use a success callback + `.done`?

Comment: What is the structure of Person? You also spelled address as "adddess" in testObj.

Comment: Try enabling tracing at the server side; the traces should tell why the server is considering the request to be bad.

Comment: @Edward adddess is just a big typo :). I fix this but the problem remains. I will post the structure

Comment: @Johan is just sample code from jquery docs for ajax post . please igonore that part .

Comment: It looks like many similar problems occur because of an incorrect json string. Try checking it at jsonlint.com

Comment: @Johan json string is ok. thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after pulling a lot of hair :) finally managed to get it to work.
basically have to use the full form of $. ajax and not $. post, in order to indicate the contenttype "application / json; charset = utf-8". Now works without realizing why this happened. Thanks to all who tried to help

Code that works for me

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../App_Services/DataService.svc/PersonAddress",
        data: objectAsJson,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
       // processdata: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("ok")
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing below line :

```
var objectAsJson = JSON.stringify({ PersonAddress: testObj });// This is adding a property "PersonAddress" to the object
```

To

```
var objectAsJson = JSON.stringify(testObj);// this is PersonAddress object itself
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it does not work. I edited the post with new information.